# How to prevent gif background from stopping

Tags: html, web, background, gif

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ressources/Css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <header>
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </header>
    <table style='width: 100%;'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="left" style="color:#ffffff;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="vertical-align:top" rowspan="3"><img onclick="" class="maTete clickable" border=3px src="Ressources/images/moa2.jpg"></th>
                        <th >
                            <div class="semi-moyen  textLeft">Nauleau Virgil</div>
                            <div class="petit textLeft">Élève en Bachelor 1</div>
                            <div class="petit textLeft">Ynov Aix-en-Provence</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="rigth moyen menu table" style="color:#ffffff  ; border:hidden">
                    <tr>
                        <th height="2px"><p class="clickable" onclick="document.location.href='aPropos/apropos.html'">À propos</p></th>
                        <th height="2px"><p class="clickable">Expérience</p></th>
                        <th height="2px"><p class="clickable" onclick="document.location.href='projets/Projet.html'">Projets</p></th>
                        <th height="2px"><p class="clickable">Contact</p></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <div style='margin-left:14vw;text-align:center;'class="part1" id=main></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Ressources/data_project.js"></script>
    <script src="Ressources/Scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

```css
html{font-size: 100%;
    scrollbar-width: thin;}
/* Global */
/* pour les dernier projets*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "Styler";
    src: url("../police/Styler.ttf");
}
h99{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
}
h {
    font-family: "Styler";
    font-size: 4.5em;
    color:#000000;
    text-align: center;
}
.tablePro {
    border: 0.5vh solid #c66103;
    border-radius: 8vh;
    width:65vw;
    border-collapse: separate; /* Don't collapse */
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.Description {
    font-size: 1.4vw;
}
hr {
    color:#c66103;
    font-size: .1em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #c66103;
}
.Txt {
    border-left: solid orange 3em;
    padding:1em;
    font: italic small-caps 1.13em cursive;
}
.ProjImg {
    border-right: solid #c66103 .25em;
    width:75%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.project{
    width: 65em;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:3vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #6b31a2b3;
    border-collapse: inherit;
}
/* */
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color:#000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
/* Position */
.center{
    margin: auto;
}
.rigth{
    margin-left: auto;
}
.left{
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* Text Pos */
.textLeft{
    text-align : left;
}
/* var */
.table{ border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 1vmin;
}
/* Taille police */ 
.moyen{font-size: 3.5vmin;}
.semi-moyen{font-size: 3vmin;}
.petit{font-size: 2vmin;}
/* Tete */
.maTete{
    height: 20vmin;
    width: 20vmin;
    margin-left: 1.5vmin;
    margin-top: 1.5vmin;
}
.haut{
    height: 0vmin;
}
.menu{
    height: 18vmin;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.banner{
    z-index: -1 ;
    background-image:url("../images/bande.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
header{
    background-color: #00000000;
    position: relative;
    height:24vmin;
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    
} 
.background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url("../images/black_hole.gif");  
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I'm in first year of development and I need to do a portpholio before graduating to second year.
I want to put a gif background but it often stop itself when I change the page and I don't know why and can't found why.
https://tenebros-portpholio.herokuapp.com
For now i've done that, I know it's not verry good but i'm trying.

I've just done a simple background-image: and put my image here.
I've tryed to load it in Js so it reload after changing the page but it's the same.

exemple of css of my main page, im doing the same for the background on each page https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFn6.png

Comment: Please add your code to here so that others can see what's wrong you have done to fix it. Also, your gif is working fine in my Latest Chrome PC.

Comment: Yea people telling me that but for me it often stop itself when i change page.
I've just done a simple background-image: and put my image here.
I've tryed to load it in Js so it reload after changing the page but it's the same.

Comment: without your code, none can tell you what's going on here. So please add your code snippet.

Comment: Is it good? I dont know what it was so ive found that on google i dont know if its what you wanted

Comment: Ahh... never mind -_- You'll have to put real code in your question, not a snapshot of it.

Comment: I think ive done it, tell me if there is something else you need.
Also i don't know if it change something but i'm the only one having this bug other people don't have the gif that stop itself

Comment: Come on bro. You'll also need to include the html codes, not only the css.

Comment: sorry, i've added it.

Comment: Alright, now ok. Before I investigate further, did you try using .mp4 format instead of the .gif? Maybe that's the reason you are having this problem. Try replacing the .gif file with .mp4. You'll find many gif to mp4 converter online.

Comment: That was not it just an actual bug with firefox, only happen for me and only on firefox so i think somefile were causing problem no more issue since the last new version.